# KMeans with huge number of clusters

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a relatively big graph that has around 6000 vertices and I have to use KMeans and see what are the 5467 clusters. I have to use a different metric that's why I gave the distance_matrix as an input. The problem with this is that since n_clusters is too big it doesn't converge. I was advised to make custom adaptations in order t make it work, but I'm not really sure what that means. That's why I am posting this question here. Any help is welcomed! Thank you!
Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

distance_matrix = floyd_warshall_numpy(G)

cluster = KMeans(n_clusters=5467)

cluster.fit(distance_matrix)

graph_labels = cluster.labels_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not advise having such a high number of clusters with Kmeans. Instead, try using [Agglomerative clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) with euclidean distance. This would allow you to find a cutoff where you can get the expected number of clusters by grouping points.

[image]

Cutting if off at 5 would give you 4 clusters while curring it off at 2 would give you more.

Dummy code -

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],[4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering().fit(X)
clustering.labels_
```

```
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

You can use a pre-computed matrix for agglomerative clustering for the same as well

Check the documentation link that I have shared.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have to do Agglomerative clustering and KMeans clustering. I did the first one without a problem, since it converges quite fast. The problem is with KMeans.

Comment: Kmeans is just clustering based on euclidean distance. you can use euclidean distance with agglomerative clustering as well. That would give you similar results but without the optimal number of clusters. you can use the hierarchical clustering method to define a cutoff.

Comment: So I have a big graph, and I needed to use as a metric shortest distance which is precalculated in the name of distance_matrix.

Comment: So you have a pre-computed distance matrix? which is not euclidean distance?

Comment: This `distance_matrix = floyd_warshall_numpy(G)` is the precomputed distances. I just feed this to KMeans.

Comment: You can use the precomputed matrix in agglomerative clustering as well. The point I am trying to suggest is that since you have a very large number of clusters, you can to use a heirarchal clustering and cut it of on the number of cluster you need. THis might be high or low in number.

Comment: Yes I know, I did the agglomerative clustering. I need KMeans not Agglomerative clustering. I understand that it is easier and it works what you said, but my task is KMeans. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: I dont understand. Kmeans IS essentially the same as agglomerative clustering with a threshold if you are using the same distance measure. They are exactly the same mathematically.

Comment: Yes but if I want to see the centroids how could one do that?

Comment: Then you can simply cluster and compute the centroids for each cluster yourself

Comment: Since you have ~5500 clusters for 6000 points, most of the points will have themselves as centroids. Only the points that are close to each other in the floyd_warshall_numpy() matrix will get "grouped" or clustered and you can find the centroid for them.

Comment: @oaksandbrooms, do let me know if you were able to solve the problem with my suggested method.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately no. My advisor said that I need to make Kmeans.

Comment: Well, you may need to get a second opinion because I doubt your advisor is suggesting the right approach :) .. But good luck. If you solve this properly with kmeans then do let me know as well., i may learn something new :))

Comment: Glad to help anytime.